# Calculating t-statistics using `scipy.stats`

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have two samples of values, measured on the same group under two different conditions:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

v1 = np.array([ 152.65285 ,   97.011475,   77.56722 ,  120.19234 ])
v2 = np.array([ 149.19984,  172.08975,  143.92285,  108.60255])
```

What I want to do is perform the [dependent t-test for paired examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples) on this particular dataset. As is seen in the wikipedia link, this is performed by calculating the *t* value using the formula:

[image]

Where `mu_0` is set to 0. I performed this calculation and calculated that the t_value is equal to

```
>>> (np.average(v1 - v2) * np.sqrt(len(v1))) / (np.std(v1 - v2))
-1.6061552162815307
```

However, using the `scipy.stats` package, I get a slightly different result:

```
>>> st.ttest_rel(v1,v2)
(-1.3909712197206947, 0.25844779134312651)
```

The first number that `st.ttest_rel(v1,v2)` returns *should*, according to the `scipy` [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind), be equal to the *t*-value, but it's *not*. Am I missing something here or is the `scipy.stats` calculating the statistic incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference seems to be that `np.std` calculates the standard deviation with `N` degrees of freedom, whereas `ttest_rel` uses a biased estimator to calculate it (`N-1` degrees of freedom).

You can fix this by specifying the difference in the degrees of freedom in `np.std` as `1`:

```
>>> (np.average(v1 - v2) * np.sqrt(len(v1))) / (np.std(v1 - v2, ddof=1))
-1.3909712197206947
```

The two calculations then agree.

Comment: Ahh, of course. The degrees of freedom for the standard deviation. Thank you for pointing that out to me. Answer accepted.

Comment: General question: If I do: ttest_rel(a, b) and the obtained t value is negative, does this mean that the mean of b is greater than the mean of a ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at scipy's sources in the `site-packages` directory of my python folder. In the file `scipy/stats/stats.py` it is shown how the ttest_rel is calculated. I found that it is done a bit differently than in your manually calculated case. But as I am not an expert in statistics, you might want to have a look at the implementation by yourself. That is the best tip I can give at the moment...

Comment: You are correct, the answer by ajcr also explains why the ttest is correct and my method is not.